# How to get the <li> element id lists at JQuery-UI sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to get all 'li' elements id such as a, b, c, ... g.

How to get all 'li' element id lists?

Thank you!

**JQuery-UI sortable example**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="a" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li id="b" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li id="c" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li id="d" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li id="e" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li id="f" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li id="g" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#sortable').find('li').each(function(){
        var listId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```